# Addition of 3 angular momenta

Tags: angular-momentum

I'm struggling to understand how the orbital angular momentum "add" in ground state Nitrogen. As I understand it N has an electron configuration of $1s^22s^22p^3$ and so the 3 outer electrons in the $l=1$ shell will combine. I've tried to combine these three by first combining two $l=1$ states to get $L = 0,1,2$ and then combining one more $l=1$ with this $L$ to get $L=0,1\textrm{(twice) },2,3$.

Am I doing this right? Because my revision worksheet says this should only have $L=0,1,2$ but I don't see why you can't have $L=3$

Comment: You seem to be forgetting Pauli's principle...

Comment: Ah right, so they can't all be pointing in the same direction because then they'd be in the same state?

Comment: Oh no, right, I get it, only two electrons could occupy the same orbital state because they could have spin up or down, but the third couldn't then join that because of Pauli exclusion